# MacOS Ventura 13.4 Siri & spotlight has options "Listen to Hey Siri" and "Allow Siri when locked" totally missing from Siri & Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight, siri, ventura

I've been facing issues in System Settings >Siri & Spotlight to show "Listen to Siri and  Allow Siri when Locked" on MacOS Ventura 13.4 on MacBook Pro Mid 2012 running with open core legacy patcher version 0.6.7. These two options are missing after updating to Ventura 13.4 in settings. I have tried all help available on the net, any help plz.
Before the update Siri worked fine and Siri responded to "hey Siri" as intended on Ventura 13.3.1

[image: screen short of the settings app]

Comment: Is Siri working at least? Try to press cmd+space for about 1 sec to enable it.

Comment: It's only supported in models from 2018 so if it worked before it must be something to do with OCLP.

Comment: @Thinkr - OP said it worked before… so it has to be something to do with OCLP, which I haven't the first clue about.

Comment: yes it worked completely fine on OCLP 0.6.6 & Mac OS 13.3.1

Comment: yes it works when I press cmd+space but it also responded to "Hey Siri " before  @Thinkr

Comment: @Abhishek Then that's probably an issue with the OCLP 0.6.7 update. Or maybe the OCLP 0.6.7 compatibility with macOS 13.4?

Comment: ok , thanks a lot ppl